# Search for tags only redirect from search page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

After performing a search on the [advanced search page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) with only tags in the search box I get redirected to tagged questions page:

1. [image: search for tags only]
2. [image: tagged questions]

The search-string on the top of the page in this case gets unfolded:

[image: unfolded search]

---

When I do the search with some extra data - I remain on the search page. And the search string stays unmodified.

[image: tags + something other]

Comment: Havn't got time to look for a dupe but this is by design (if you're searching for a specific tag then the questions on the tag page *are* what you're looking for)